# Recognize \ literally in Python strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve the list of indices of each sub-string within a string. This string contains the special character \ several times in different places within the string. The \ should be recognized as a character and not as a special character. When I obtain the starting index of the sub-string it skips over the \ and returns one index less than what it should be. Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

```
text = "ab\fx*abcdfansab\fasdafdab\f664s"
for m in re.finditer( 'ab\f', text ):
print( 'll found', m.start(), m.end() )
```

('ll found', 0, 3)
('ll found', 13, 16)
('ll found', 22, 25)

The second index should be (14, 17) and the third (24, 27). Also, I'm not sure why the first one is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python interpreting the `\` as an escape character, like many other programming languages do. If you want a literal backslash, use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), and also double the `\` in the pattern, since [backslash is a regex metacharacter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special):

```
>>> text = r'ab\fx*abcdfansab\fasdafdab\f664s'
>>> for m in re.finditer( r'ab\\f', text ):
...    print( 'll found', m.start(), m.end() )
...
('ll found', 0, 4)
('ll found', 14, 18)
('ll found', 24, 28)
```

Alternately, [double the backslashes everywhere, and don't use raw strings](http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html). Again, remember to doubly escape in the regex.

```
>>> text = 'ab\\fx*abcdfansab\\fasdafdab\\f664s'
>>> for m in re.finditer( 'ab\\\\f', text ):
...     print( 'll found', m.start(), m.end() )
... 
('ll found', 0, 4)
('ll found', 14, 18)
('ll found', 24, 28)
```

Comment: raw string would include the slash while still interperting it as an escape character.

Comment: Awesome! It worked this time! Just wondering why though it's only a single \ in the text but a \\ in the for loop?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I get it. On a related note though... If I'm using variables instead, could I use raw strings? Or some other way?

Comment: It all depends on where the values of those variables come from. No worries about the first post – everyone here was new once.

Answer (score 0):

To find non-overlapping occurences of a substring:

```
haystack = r"ab\fx*abcdfansab\fasdafdab\f664s" # raw-literal to interpret
                                               # the backslash literally
needle = r"ab\f"
n = len(needle)
i = -n
while True:
    i = haystack.find(needle, i+n)
    if i == -1:
        break
    print((i, i+n))
```

Or using a regex:

```
import re

print("\n".join(str((m.start(), m.end()))
                for m in re.finditer(re.escape(needle), haystack)))
```

Both produce the same output:

```
(0, 4)
(14, 18)
(24, 28)
```